# Setting data on Session not working ( different behavior on 2 server)

Tags: api, session

I need to store some data on Session during a call to Magento API, so I have overwritten `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart_Customer_Api` and added this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCustomVar('value');
```

The above code works fine on my local server but on Live server it is not storing anything on session (even If i just store a fix string )

Any idea ?

Comment: If you do an immediate var_dump of $session->getData() what does it return on your live server?

Comment: not easy to do what you ask because I'm doing it on the base of an API call.
If i test it in a normal script (not API) it works also on server

Comment: Use `Mage::log($session->getData());` and it should push it out to your system.log file

Comment: Doing that, session is there but without my data

Answer (score 2):

This session is not available when executing via the API.  Depending on what you are doing try saving that data to the customer or quote object ( would require you create a custom attribute ).

Its hard to give you proper direction without knowing what you are trying to save and how you plan to use it later.  Try to be more descriptive

Comment: I just give up and found another way.